# Exchange 2010 - Mailbox Export much larger than actual size

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2010, powershell, mailbox

I issue this command to export the mailbox of a user:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox "user" -FilePath "\\server\share\user.pst"
```

After 2 minutes or so, this file have been generated:
[image]

Notice the size of the export file, and now this is the actual size of the mailbox on the server as seen from outlook:

[image]

Where does this extra ~100MB in the export file comes from?

Answer (score 3):

It is likely the additional items that are exported, such as the recoverable deleted items (dumpster).

I would mount the .PST file in your outlook profile and check each folder to see exactly where the additional mail items are.

A mailbox export will export EVERYTHING within the mailbox, including items that aren't viewable to the user.

Comment: It may also be related to message compression. I'm assuming that you'd lose that on a mailbox export. - http://sysadmin-talk.org/2010/07/exchange-2010-compression

Comment: @joeqwerty ah, very interesting, I had not seen that before.  I would imagine you'd lose the compression on an export too.

Comment: Agreed.  OP can check this with: Get-MailboxStatistics <Identity> | Format-List StorageLimitStatus,TotalItemSize,TotalDeletedItemSize,ItemCount,DeletedItemCount

Answer (score 2):

I have found the reason.

The export contains all the deleted and purged messages of the mailbox, even after the "Deleted Elements" have been emptied in outlook. So once I opened the archive into outlook, I saw all my emails that I have deleted and purged months ago.

That's a good thing I learnt, thanks to you guys!

Comment: If the answer I provided you was what you were looking for, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can check using the below command:

**Get-MailboxStatistics  | Format-List StorageLimitStatus,TotalItemSize,TotalDeletedItemSize,ItemCount,DeletedItemCount**

because Exported .pst includes deleted items.